# ASP.NET MVC JQuery Autocomplete TextBox doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a List of students and i am trying to implement a search bar that autocomplete itself.

Here are my controller methods

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchForStudents(StudentViewModel studentViewModel)
{
    return PartialView("_StudentListTable", 
_repository.GetStudentViewModel(studentViewModel.SearchStudent));
}

public JsonResult AutoComplete(string term)
{
    var model = _repository.FetchGeneralStudentSearchResult(term);
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The SearchForStudents method is called when the search is made (this part works well). Now the part that doesn't work is the AutoComplete method. This method is meant to be called each time the user types something in the searchbox. But it is not called.. ever..

Here is my razor view

```
@using Bulletin.Models
@model Bulletin.Models.StudentViewModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchForStudents", "Admin", null, new AjaxOptions {             
HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId =         
"StudentTableList" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchStudent, "", new { @type = 
"string", @data_autocomplete_source = Url.Action("AutoComplete") })
    <input type="submit" name="searchbt" value="Search" />
}

<hr />
<div id="StudentTableList">
    @Html.Partial("_StudentListTable")
</div>


@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/MonScript.js"></script>
}
```

And here is the "MonScript.js" file supposedly in charge of detecting the input and calling the method

```
$(function () {
    $("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
        var target = $(this);
        target.autocomplete({ source: target.attr("data_autocomplete_source") });
    });
});
```

So my question i guess is why doesn't it work and whay can I do to fix this? Thank you in advance for any help :D

EDIT : Here is what razor is interpreted as

```
<form action="/Admin/SearchForStudents" data-ajax="true" data-ajax- 
method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#StudentTableList" 
id="form0" method="post">
    <input data-autocomplete-source="/Admin/AutoComplete" id="SearchStudent" 
     name="SearchStudent" type="string" value="" />    
    <input type="submit" name="searchbt" value="Search" />
</form>
```

EDIT 2 : The browser's console sends me an exception

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.source is not a function
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._search 
(http://localhost:49741/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js:6015:8)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._search 
(http://localhost:49741/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js:144:25)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).search 
(http://localhost:49741/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js:6007:15)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).search 
(http://localhost:49741/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js:144:25)
    at $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function).<anonymous> 
(http://localhost:49741/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js:5988:10)
    at handlerProxy (jquery-ui-1.12.1.js:641)
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Any console errors in your browser? Does the AJAX request even fire? Does your .each code even actually select any elements and add the autocomplete to them? You don't seem to have investigated much, or if you have, you haven't told us about it.

Comment: Well if i place a breakpoint on the .each the debugger does go through it on loading the page but not when typing in the textbox. I do not have any error or exceptions launched which is why I am so baffled

Comment: I wouldn't expect the debugger to fire the .each when typing in the box, if that's what you mean. No other errors? Does the ajax call ever happen? One thing - shouldn't `target.attr("data_autocomplete_source")` be `target.attr("data-autocomplete-source")` - I think razor will automatically turn the `_` into an `-` to make it like a normal data- attribute

Comment: Well yes when i click on the Search button the Ajax sends and the partial view updates normally and works correctly. Changing "_" by "-" did nothign :/

Comment: I suggest you check the page source to see what data-attribute is actually being rendered and how it looks. Debug to see whether `target.attr("data_autocomplete_source")` actually returns a valid URl. This is all about debugging. Also consider editing your question to show us the finalised HTML, not just the Razor source. jQuery can only see the final HTML, that's what it operates on, not the Razor. So without seeing that, I'm never going to be 100% sure what your final page actually looks like

Comment: Anyway I didn't mean that AJAX request, I meant the one which would be triggered by the autocomplete, obviously, since that's what we're talking about.

Comment: Yes it does return a valid URI, the one we want actually. But the Ajax request is never sent for some reason